# How to correctly add event listener to React useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, autodesk-forge

I am trying to add an event listener to an Autodesk Forge viewer. This is an application built on React and this is the code I am trying:

```
  const selectEvent = () => {
    let viewer = window.NOP_VIEWER;
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (e) => {
      setSelection(e.dbIdArray);
    });
  };
```

This runs perfectly when called from a button `onClick`:

```
<Button onClick={() => selectEvent()}>Add</Button>
```

However, I would like the event listener to turn on when the page is loaded, so I tried `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let viewer = window.NOP_VIEWER;
    if (viewer) {
      selectEvent();
    }
  }, []);
```

Even after trying some modifications, I could not get it to work. Nothing happens, so I suspect the event listener never gets added. Looking around at other solutions, event listeners are usually loaded with `useEffect`, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any tips would be appreciated!

edit: It does enter the `if` statement, as a `console.log` works

Some background (might be relevant):
The viewer is loaded from a `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeViewer(props);
  }, []);
```

and the viewer can be accessed as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this. 
When ever change in `viewer` and viewer is available, then you register the event. 
Deregister the event handler as return function to hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (viewer) {
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (e) => {
      setSelection(e.dbIdArray);
    });
  }
  return () => { /* do the removeEventLister */ }
}, [viewer]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**NOP_VIEWER is a global variable to access the current Viewer**

you need to remove the event listener after listening otherwise it will cause memory leak

```
useEffect(()=>{
  NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (e) => {
      setSelection(e.dbIdArray);
    });
return()=>{NOP_VIEWER.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (e) => {
      setSelection(e.dbIdArray);
    }))}
},[])
```

or if it doesn't work

```
useEffect(()=>{
  let viewer= window.NOP_VIEWER
  viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (e) => {
      setSelection(e.dbIdArray);
    });

},[])
```